If or ternary operator in bc
I want to write
level=$( echo "scale=0; ( 254 * ( if ( $1 > 100 ) { 100 } else { $1 } ) ) / 100" | bc )

but it appears to be impossible. Is this so?

In bc like C and C++ (and awk) comparisons yield 1 or 0 so you can do (254*($1-($1>100)*($1-100))/100

Use awk instead:
awk "BEGIN { if ( $h < 13 ) { print 13 - $h } else { print 1 }; exit }"


That's a statement, not an operator/expression, and an if statement also works in bc. awk also has the operator: awk -vh=5 'BEGIN{print h<13? 13-h: 1}'

@dave_thompson_085 : make that '{ print (13 - h)^(h < 13) }' to make a statement that actually prints conditionally
